# SQL server like statement for second word

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a WHERE myColumn like -Second Word is "is"-. 
Since I can't use regular expressions, I'm not how I can do this. '% is' returns results that have the word is later on... Is this even possible ?

Comment: If it is enough for checking if it is in a column not at the beginning nor the end but in the middle then do `like '% is %`

Comment: I need it to be exactly the second word.

Comment: You could also use a substring function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but this will work :

```
select * from MyTable 
   where MyColumn like '%[ ]SearchTerm%' and 
         CHARINDEX(' ', MyColumn, 0) + 1 = CHARINDEX('SearchTerm', MyColumn, 0)
```

This assumes a table called MyTable, a column to look in called MyColumn and a string to look for of "SearchTerm"

Comment: I used this, and it worked without a hitch. Speed was good, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTB
WHERE SUBSTRING(TestColumn, CHARINDEX('-', TestColumn, 1), CHARINDEX('-', TestColumn, 1) + 1) LIKE '%Val%'
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82b68/11/0)